# RabbitMQ Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: rabbitmq

We are using rabbitmq 3.6.9 version install on a single linux box. As part of the client security vulnerability check following concerns are raised for rabbitmq server.

Can anyone please guide us on resolving the following vulnerabilities.

1. DOM-based Cross Site Scripting Vulnerability (http-client-side-xss)
2. jQuery Vulnerability: CVE-2012-6708 (jquery-cve-2012-6708)
3. jQuery Vulnerability: CVE-2014-6071 (jquery-cve-2014-6071)

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Update to latest version?

Comment: More over RabbitMQ 3.6.x series has been eol for over a year now...

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ `3.6.9` is ***over two years old***!

It makes ***absolutely no sense*** to run security checks on old software!

You should be using RabbitMQ 3.8.0 or 3.7.19.